# Query to select records from a database that were created within the last 24 hours

Tags: php, database, timestamp

I am wondering how to query to the database to show results that have been submitted in the last 24 hours.

In the table, `topics`, I have a collumn set up called `start_date` which uses timestamps.  How would I query the database to find the topics created in the last 24 hours?

Basically, I want to do something like this, but not sure how to use `WHERE`:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE start_date = 'LAST 24 HOURS?'");
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like this;

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE start_date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)");
```

**Edited:** the math of `NOW() - 60*60*24` was wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE start_date >= ".time() - 24 * 3600);
```

This is asking your database for all topics with a start date timestamp greater than or equal to the timestamp 24 hours ago. Note that you can use a `DATETIME` column too, with only a slight modification:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE start_date >= '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 24 * 3600)."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

... where start_date > @date

and your date should be mention to time 1 day before now...

Jimmy's query shall run well too !