# Query to select records from a database that were created from a certain time in the past until now

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp

I'm relatively a newbie, would appreciate help :)

I am looking to find entry(ies) from a mysql table which were created some time between now and a certain timestamp in the past. This time in the past is stored in a variable (say $timeinthepast, a few hours ago or yesterday, whatever). And the column 'timecreated' in the table is the timestamp of the creation of entry.

Would the following work? If not, what would?

Thanks!

```
    <?php

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 
                 WHERE timecreated = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -$timeinthepast)");

    ?>
```

I am basing this on: [Query to select records from a database that were created within the last 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052264/query-to-select-records-from-a-database-that-were-created-within-the-last-24-hou)

Comment: Is `$timeinthepast` always in the same unit? Like hours, minutes, days, etc...

Comment: it's a timestamp, at a certain point in the site it is set: '$timeinthepast=time();'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `$timeinthepast` is valid (`1 MONTH`, `2 HOUR`, e.g.) in the sql you can try `BETWEEN`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 
         WHERE timecreated BETWEEN 
         DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $timeinthepast) AND NOW()");
```

Comment: $timeinthepast is a timestamp as well: `$timeinthepast=time();` somewhere else on the website before the current code. thanks! I'll try `between`, looks great

Comment: and can I add this to another `WHERE` with `AND`? meaning, is the following okay?: `WHERE column1='$foo' AND (column2='Bar' OR column2='bar' OR column2='b') AND timecreated BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $timeinthepast) AND NOW()`

Comment: this does not seem to be working :( is it because $timeinthepast is a specific timestamp and not a time period?

Comment: If `$timeinthepast` is set to the `time()` format you can use `strtotime()` like so: `... WHERE timecreated BETWEEN " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($timeinthepast)) . " AND NOW()`

Answer (score 0):

I find that the between syntax is the most freindly to use. I have not tested this sorry :)

```
Select * from `table1` where `timecreated` between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL  1 month)  and NOW()
```

You will need to make your time in the past a whole unit of some description.

Comment: `BETWEEN` syntax is `[min] AND [max]` so you'd have to switch it in your example.  Also, `INTERVAL` is `expr` `type` so it'd be `INTERVAL 1 MONTH`